# Gradient Layer covers all items in Collection View with no respect of spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cagradientlayer

So I'm using a third party library called [Scaling Carousel](https://github.com/superpeteblaze/ScalingCarousel) and for the most part it's been pretty good but for some reason when I try to customize it and add gradient layers to it or even a shadow it doesnt get affixed properly? I've included a picture below for reference.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        var view = UILabel()

        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 236, height: 130)

        let layer0 = CAGradientLayer()

               layer0.colors = [

                 UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.46, blue: 0.467, alpha: 1).cgColor,

                 UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.36, blue: 0.369, alpha: 1).cgColor

               ]

               layer0.locations = [0, 1]

               layer0.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.25, y: 0.5)

               layer0.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)

               layer0.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(a: -1, b: 1, c: -1, d: -2.48, tx: 1.5, ty: 1.24))

        layer0.bounds = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: -0.5*view.bounds.size.width, dy: -0.5*view.bounds.size.height)

        layer0.position = view.center


        view.layer.addSublayer(layer0)

        cell.addSubview(view)


        if let scalingCell = cell as? ScalingCarouselCell {
            scalingCell.mainView.backgroundColor = .white

        }
```

Here's the scalingcarousel code

```
open class ScalingCarouselCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // MARK: - Properties (Public)

    /// The minimum value to scale to, should be set between 0 and 1
    open var scaleMinimum: CGFloat = 0.9

    /// Divisior used when calculating the scale value.
    /// Lower values cause a greater difference in scale between subsequent cells.
    open var scaleDivisor: CGFloat = 10.0

    /// The minimum value to alpha to, should be set between 0 and 1
    open var alphaMinimum: CGFloat = 0.85

    // MARK: - IBOutlets

    // This property should be connected to the main cell subview
    @IBOutlet public var mainView: UIView!

    // MARK: - Overrides

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        guard let carouselView = superview as? ScalingCarouselView else { return }

        scale(withCarouselInset: carouselView.inset)
    }

    override open func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        mainView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        mainView.alpha = 1.0

    }


    /// Scale the cell when it is scrolled
    ///
    /// - parameter carouselInset: The inset of the related SPBCarousel view
    open func scale(withCarouselInset carouselInset: CGFloat) {

        // Ensure we have a superView, and mainView
        guard let superview = superview,
            let mainView = mainView else { return }

        // Get our absolute origin value
        let originX = superview.convert(frame, to: superview.superview).origin.x

        // Calculate our actual origin.x value using our inset
        let originXActual = originX - carouselInset

        let width = frame.size.width

        // Calculate our scale values
        let scaleCalculator = abs(width - abs(originXActual))
        let percentageScale = (scaleCalculator/width)

        //Calculate distance between our carousel views
        let scaleValue = scaleMinimum
        //Add the following line for a greater carousel effect.
        //+ (percentageScale/scaleDivisor)

        let alphaValue = alphaMinimum
            + (percentageScale/scaleDivisor)

        let affineIdentity = CGAffineTransform.identity

        // Scale our mainView and set it's alpha value
        mainView.transform = affineIdentity.scaledBy(x: scaleValue, y: scaleValue)
        mainView.alpha = 1.0

        // ..also..round the corners
        mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 28
```

[image: without gradient code]
[image: with gradient code]

Comment: Note that even if I change the frame size of the UILabel I get the same result.

Comment: This looks rather convoluted. For one, you are creating a new `UILabel` and adding to the cell in `cellForItemAt` ... but cells are ***reused*** so you'll end up adding multiple labels to the same cell. You'd be much better off editing your cell class and implementing your gradient layer when the cell is created. Also, you may get more help if you show how your cell looks now and how you *want* it to look (as opposed to just showing how wrong it looks).

Comment: @DonMag Thank you for the feedback, Don! So the top picture is closer to how I want the cells to look (even though they're not quite that) in terms of shape. The bottom is how they look right now. I want them to keep that gradient layer on top. I tried adding the gradient to just the mainview and I still go the same results. Additionally I'm only using UILabel as an example, what I wanted to do honestly was just add a UIView.

Comment: OK - we still need more clarity... Have you created a prototype cell in Storyboard? Do you have code that is creating the red view with one rounded corner?

Comment: By prototype cell do you mean a cell via IB? Yes I have. And the code for the rounded corner is added via updated above.

Comment: OK - so, the red rect with rounded top-left corner is `mainView`? And, since you have  `mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 28`, which would round all 4 corners, I assume `mainView` extends outside the bounds of its superview (the cell)? Is this what you're going for (with the colors exaggerated for clarity)?   https://i.imgur.com/2iyqhy5.png

Comment: TBH I want the whole of mainview to fit its cell I just don't know how. But with regards to color, yes that's what I'm going for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207294/discussion-between-kfdoom-and-donmag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a `UIView` subclass with the gradient and corner radius logic inside.

So, first, add this code to your project:

```
@IBDesignable
class KFGradientView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    private var gLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        gLayer.type = .axial

        gLayer.colors = [
            UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.46, blue: 0.467, alpha: 1).cgColor,
            UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.36, blue: 0.369, alpha: 1).cgColor
        ]
        gLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.25, y: 0.5)
        gLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)

        // exaggerated colors so it's obvious
        // remove or comment-out this to use original red-ish colors
        gLayer.colors = [
            UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1).cgColor,
            UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        ]

        gLayer.cornerRadius = 28
    }

}
```

Next, for a quick test, add a view controller to your Storyboard and add a `UIView` subview. Change that view's class to `KFGradientView` (ignore the *scratchy* -- you should see the name of your project there):

[image]

From the top menu bar, select `Editor -> Refresh All Views` (or have `Automatically Refresh Views` checked). You should see this:

[image]

Assuming you do, go to your Collection View Cell prototype, and change the class of `mainView` from `UIView` to `KFGradientView`. You should see the same thing happen there.

Then, remove this line from your `func scale(...)` in your `class ScalingCarouselCell: UICollectionViewCell`:

```
mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 28
```

and change your `cellForItemAt` func to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ScalingCarouselCell

    return cell
}
```

As far as your `mainView` not getting sized / positioned in the cell correctly, well, that's an entirely different issue. If you can't figure it out, post that as a new question.

Comment: Thank you, this works but as precisely as you said, I'm not sure how to get the mainView positioned in the cell correctly. Been trying to figure this out for days. Ha. Ha. *kills self*